# How does MEMS low insertion loss fiber optic switch work?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, experimental-technique, fiber-optics

I'm currently looking for a low insertion loss fiber optic switch to be able to change the light source of a spectrometer. Since this will be used in harsh conditions, I was hoping to find one with no moving parts.

Today I found this **[low insertion loss fiber optic switch](https://www.gracy-fiber.com/micro-optic/optical-switch/mems-fiber-optic-switches.html)**, it appears to be a fiber optic switch with no moving parts. Although I can't use such a switch due to the inappropriate wavelength range, I would like to know how these switches work. So far I've only seen optomechanical devices, which I'm assuming use some sort of actuated mirror assembly to redirect light from the correct input fiber to the output fiber. On a smaller scale, I've seen piezoelectric devices just move the physical output fiber side to side by tiny amounts.

I read somewhere about a magneto-optic crystal, which seems to be a crystal whose transmission is based on the voltage applied to it. How does this achieve such a switch? Is there any other way?

Comment: The description on the page to which you linked is vague, but when they say, MEMS, I think of a [Digital Micromirror Device](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_micromirror_device) or DMD, which actually _does_ have moving parts, but those parts are microscopically small.

Comment: There are several devices using electric fields to alter the index of materials (electro active ceramics for example) to change the matching to select one of several outputs from one input.